# Chrome driver for Selenium stuck in grey screen on bet365 site

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I’ve got grey screen when was trying to open bet365 site using Chrome driver and Selenium.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bet365.it/");
```

[image]

Comment: Please someone breake this protection.

Comment: Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071572/out-of-memory-error-in-pythonselenium-first-load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I executed your usecase with a couple of tweaks and faced the same consequences. Here are the execution details:

- Code Block [*Python*]:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.bet365.it/')
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: bet365]

---

### Deep Dive

When I checked the [Terms and conditions](https://help.bet365.it/it/terms-and-conditions) it is clearly mentioned that:

> 6. Other
>
> 6.1 bet365 actively monitors traffic to and from its Site. Bet365 reserves the right to block access to the Site, at its discretion,
> should it encounter any evidence of automated or robotized game
> activity.

---

### Conclusion

It seems [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) based browsing context is getting detected and the navigation is blocked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right. Looks like this is only one possible way how to fix it - use mobile version. Looks like bet365 doesn't block mobile version.

Comment: They are now blocking the mobile, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": 
"""Object.defineProperty(navigator, 
'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})"""})

url = 'https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/B1'
driver.get(url)
sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you describe what the fix is?

Comment: it will not be gray screen.

Comment: I still get the issue with this

Answer (score 0):

[Python]

using [selenium-profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) with [selenium-driverless](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Driverless)

```py
from selenium_profiles.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium_profiles.profiles import profiles
from selenium_driverless.webdriver import ChromeOptions
import time

profile = profiles.Windows() # or .Android
options = ChromeOptions()
driver = Chrome(profile=profile, options=options, driverless_options=True)

back = driver.current_window_handle
# get url
driver.get('https://bet365.com')
driver.switch_to.target(driver.targets[0]["targetId"])

time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.target(back)


driver.quit()  # Execute on the End!
```

works for me

selenium-driverless uses the `chrome-developer-protocol` only

Note: I am the developer of those Packages, use for educational purposes only!